# Shapefile reprojection with "sf" R package doesn't work

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I am using the `sf` R package to work with a shapefile (with a species distribution).

```
> sp #this is the shapefile
```

returns:

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -11539950 ymin: 4933183 xmax: 11985800 ymax: 8012809
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
            scntfcN                       geometry
3096 Myodes rutilus MULTIPOLYGON (((5070195 797...
```

These are the shapefile crs and plot:

```
> crs(sp) #show the original crs
[1] "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
> plot(sp) #plot the original shapefile
```

[image]

I want to reproject the shapefile from the Mollweide projection to the WGS84 geographic crs:

```
> sp_reproj <- st_transform(sp, 4326) #reproject the shapefile

> crs(sp_reproj)
```

returns:

```
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

but when I try to plot it, I get this error:

```
> plot(sp_reproj)
Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) : 
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or 1 elements.
```

Furthermore, if I write the shapefile

```
> st_write(sp_reproj, "Reprojection.shp")
```

and open it with QGIS, I have this:

[image]

Strangely, the holes (lakes) seems to have been filled.

Further notes:
1) the original sp shapefile seems to be valid and not empty

```
> st_is_valid(sp)
[1] TRUE
> st_is_empty(sp)
[1] FALSE
```

2) My final aim is not just to plot the reprojected shapefile, but to intersect it with a raster. However, I get the same error as when plotting, so the problem should be in the shapefile not in the operation.

3) Actually, the `sp` shapefile come from a bigger shapefile with thousand of sf features. This one is the only one that gives me that error.

4) [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SJTEdcUR-V268zQ0YVHOgXqhvH0R9l23) the original and reprojected shapefiles

Why I get this error? And why the reprojection fill the holes in the original shapefile?

Comment: Error dissected and fixed below, I don't know why QGIS paints the lakes, that might be another question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `sp` object is a `MULTIPOLYGON` - lets break it into `POLYGON` objects and see if there's something afoot:

```
> sp2 = st_cast(sp$geometry,"POLYGON")
> length(sp2)
[1] 40
```

Its 40 separate `POLYGON` units. At this point `plot(sp2)` works and looks fine. Now transform those 40 units and plot:

```
> sp2t = st_transform(sp2, 4326)
> plot(sp2t)
Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) : 
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements.
```

Great, we've reproduced your error, which is the first step to fixing it. Now which of the 40 units is the problem? A little testing reveals:

```
> plot(sp2t[1:39])
```

works fine. but...

```
> plot(sp2t[40])
Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) : 
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements.
```

What is that pesky object?

```
> sp2t[40]
Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 179.9987 ymin: 67.11926 xmax: 179.9987 ymax: 67.11926
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
POLYGON ((179.9987 67.11926))
```

It appears to be a polygon with only one point. What did it start out as?

```
> sp2[40]
Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 9936218 ymin: 7483013 xmax: 10072890 ymax: 7528533
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
POLYGON ((9936320 7528522, 10072891 7483013, 99...
```

which is a polygon of four coordinates:

```
> st_coordinates(sp2[40])
            X       Y L1 L2
[1,]  9936320 7528522  1  1
[2,] 10072891 7483013  1  1
[3,]  9936218 7528533  1  1
[4,]  9936320 7528522  1  1
```

which transformed becomes one point:

```
> st_coordinates(sp2t[40])
            X        Y L1 L2
[1,] 179.9987 67.11926  1  1
```

The original polygon is a tiny sliver at the top right. It has an area that is about one ten-millionth of the total area:

```
> sum(st_area(sp2))
1.846842e+13 [m^2]
> st_area(sp2[40])
1600110 [m^2]
```

and it is probably being reprojected to a point because of edge problems with the transformation. Let's try projecting each point in polygon 40:

```
> p40pts = st_cast(sp2[40],"POINT")
> st_transform(p40pts, 4326)
Geometry set for 4 features  (with 3 geometries empty)
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 179.9987 ymin: 67.11926 xmax: 179.9987 ymax: 67.11926
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
POINT EMPTY
POINT EMPTY
POINT (179.9987 67.11926)
POINT EMPTY
```

Empty geometries. These are probably right on the edge or even over the edge of that Mollweide projection.

So what to do? I reckon this sliver is negligible, so you can rebuild your spatial data by dropping it and remaking a MULTIPOLYGON object if you need it:

```
> spfix = sp2t[1:39]
> spfixu = st_union(spfix)
> plot(spfixu, col="brown")
```

[image]

and the lakes are preserved as holes.

Comment: Nice.     (now some extraneous padding so I can comment)